# In most countries I will get sacked for this

Tags: riddle

In my country,

> I have a 24 hour job but I am never awake doing my job
>
> In most countries I will get fired for doing this.
>
> Yet here, folks show a lot of respect to me.

I am important

Who am I?

Comment: I think this should have the knowledge tag.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This may be a cop out but are you a

> [sleeping policeman](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sleeping_policeman) - a British term for a speed bump. Road traffic should slow down, but in other countries this implies a policeman sleeping, which if on the job, would be a risk to it.

Comment: +1 for rot13(gur onq cha!)

Comment: Actually, that is also the term we use in Indonesia :)

Comment: The term is also used in some Caribbean countries. Some countries like Russia and Columbia use "Lying-down" policeman for the speed bumps. Go figure.

Comment: Though @DEEM 's user profile claims USA, where I've never heard the term (might be regional here?)

Comment: Can confirm athin's =)
I'm actually surprised that this term is used somewhere else too

Comment: same term used also in Latvia

Answer (score 30):

You are

> [Kim Il Sŏng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Il-sung)

```
In my country,
```

> [North Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Korea)

```
I have a 24 hour job
```

> you are the [Eternal President](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_leaders_of_North_Korea#%22Eternal_President%22) since 1998

```
but I am never awake doing my job
```

> well, [you are dead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_and_state_funeral_of_Kim_Il-sung)

```
In most countries I will get fired for doing this.
```

> if a president dies, he/she/they is/are removed from the office automatically. There are even procedures to remove comatose presidents from the office.

```
Yet here, folks show a lot of respect to me.
```

> You bet!

```
I am important
```

> Of course - the whole [North Korean ideology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juche) revolves around your legacy

Comment: This is my favourite answer!

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> A sleeper agent

Because

> Your job is just a cover. When "activated" you will do some sabotage, but for now, you're "sleeping". If people found out, you would be fired from your "cover" job. But back home, you're a hero.

Answer (score 9):

You are

> an alarm clock

because

> Your job is to wait 24 hours and sound an alarm.
>  Basically you are sleeping for 24 hours.
>  A worker who sleeps during their job would be fired.
>  Most people obey and get up when the alarm clock so orders.

Comment: Not sure what "my country" refers to in that case, though.

Comment: But how does this match the second line of the riddle?

Comment: Not sure how a clock will get fired though

Comment: Yeah I am not totally satisfied either.  it doesn't explain why "in my country" and "in most countries".

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> A Fire Alarm?

Reasoning

> A fire alarm must be active 24/7 to be effective, but a majority of that time it isn't actively sounding. Pulling a fire alarm when there isn't a fire can cause someone to lose their job, especially if the alarm activates a sprinkler system. Fire alarms are often seen as necessary devices in buildings, thus making them "respected".

Answer (score 8):

Are you

> A nuclear weapon?

And your job is

> Mutually Assured Destruction

Reasoning

> M.A.D. is supposed to deter WW3 24 hours a day. Because WW3 hasn't happened, its
>  reasonable to say "I am never awake doing my job." On the other hand, when talking
>  about the future, its reasonable to say "I will get fired for doing this job." The
>  respect line does accurately express the sentiment many people have towards nuclear
>  weapons.